# How to preserve selection when changing contents of an HTML element

Tags: javascript, dom, selection

I would like to be able to preserve the users' selection when I change the contents of an HTML element.  If the element is updated while the beginning or end of the selection happens to be inside, the entire selection is lost.  This also happens while dragging to create a selection, so that if the user is dragging a selection and the element's inner HTML is updated while the cursor is over the element, the user must start over.

I have a `<span>` that contains a time in the format 'hh:mm:ss am' and is updated each second.  The length of the text never changes, so that isn't an issue.

I have tried the following:

```
var s = window.getSelection();
if (!s.isCollapsed) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.setStart(s.anchorNode,s.anchorOffset);
    range.setEnd(s.focusNode,s.focusOffset);
}

document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = new Date().toString();

if (typeof range != 'undefined') { s.removeAllRanges(); s.addRange(range); }
```

It's the best my research has yielded, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

What should I do to prevent the selection from vanishing if it happens to start or end in this span?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the selection again: `range.selectNodeContents(newNode);`

```
newNode = document.getElementById("[span id]");
```

Comment: I do not want to select the entire mode.  I want to preserve whatever selection the user has on the page at the moment, whether or not it's inside or partially inside the time span.